# Pandas: Dataframe with start & end date to daily data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert below data on daily basis based on range available in start_date_ist & end_date_ist column.

[image]

I tried to use explode function, but its not supported in my current version of pandas ('0.24.0')
Is there any alternative for doing same.

```
rent_df["date"] = rent_df.apply(
    lambda x: pd.date_range(x["start_date_ist"], x["end_date_ist"]), axis=1
)

rent_df = (
    rent_df.explode("date", ignore_index=True)
    .drop(columns=["start_date_ist", "end_date_ist"])
)
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'explode'
```

Comment: What _is_ your pandas version?

Comment: @richardec: i am using '0.24.0' version

Comment: Wow, so close. `explode` was added in `0.25.0`. I'll come up with a different solution tho ;)

Comment: @richardec: getting error cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. may be its due to multiple entry of outlet_ids

Comment: Can you add the full error you're getting to the question?

Answer (score 1):

As workaround for the lack of `explode`, you can use `np.repeat` with `df.reindex` to expand the dataframe, and then `df.groupby` with `level=0` to expand the arrays:

```
new_idx = np.arange(df.shape[0]).repeat(df['date'].apply(len))
df = df.reindex(new_idx)

df['date'] = df.groupby(level=0)['date'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([*x.iloc[0]])).droplevel(1)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```